# jQuery ajax call does not open requested site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I got a

```
<button id="myid">
```

in my HTML code.
In my JS-file I try to catch the click event and call a specific URL - just like clicking a normal HTML-link.

This is what I did:

```
$('#myid').on('click', function () {
    doSomething();
});

var doSomething = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/targetURL",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

So - the URL is called, but the response is not shown - I guess because this is a ajax call. But how can I handle that?

Comment: Add a `success` handler to the AJAX call to deal with the data returned from a successful request: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you handle the `error` function you should handle the `success()` function which triggers if the [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call is succesfull.

Also you don't need to set `async: true` because it is set to `true` by default.

Add `.preventDefualt()` to `click` function to make sure that when you click the button the only thing is happening is the function that you want to trigger.

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething();
});

var doSomething= function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/targetURL",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The `data` parameter in the `success()` function the data that ajax returns. So when you log into the console you can see the structre so that you know what to do with it later.

Answer (score 0):

The *entire point* of Ajax is that it *doesn't* cause navigation but gives the response to JavaScript instead.

If you want to navigate to the new page, don't use Ajax.

Use a link.

If you want it to look like a button, apply CSS to it.

Answer (score 0):

To catch the response data, You need to add success function like the error function.

```
var doSomething = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/targetURL",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

}

Or if you only want to open an another url like normal html, you should use JS window objet

```
var doSomething = function () {
    window.open('/targetURL');
}
```